# How to make Task Scheduler open a Document with a specific program?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have Windows 10 Task Scheduler opening a specific .rtf (also tried changing it to .docx) file on workstation unlock. At present it opens automatically with Wordpad, but **I want it to open using another word processing program instead (WPS Office)**.

I've set the "default app" for .rtf and .docx files to WPS Office, but for some reason it still insists on opening with Wordpad. I've also tried restarting the computer, but it still uses Wordpad.

I've tried changing the file type to .ext, which stops it automatically opening in Wordpad, but instead it asks me which program I want to use to open the file every time ("how do you want to open this file?"), even though the default for .ext files is set to WPS Office.
Adding a step to the task to open WPS Office before the step that opens the specific file (image below) just results in the "how do you want to open this file" box appearing momentarily and then WPS Office opening but no file opening.

[image: Image of Task's Actions]

Comment: I am looking at an Office task here. Properties so you can edit. Then add your program in a cmd line format and see if you can point to a *.ext format. I think that should work

Comment: WPS Office?  Care much [about intellectual property](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/c740rj/how_trustworthy_is_wps_office/)?

Comment: @dannyzee4 if you find the solution is working, please accept (click the tick mark) on the answer by Saaransh and vote accordingly. I've suggested an edit to remove part of your post that should be posted as a comment on the answer. Feel free to repost that on the appropriate comment section.

Answer (score 0):

**This command works:**

```
path/to/wps/office.exe "path/to/the/file.rtf"
```

In this case, which is:

```
"%appdata%\..\local\Kingsoft\Wps office\ksolaunch.exe" "%userprofile%\documents\dailyorganisationdocument.ext"
```